# How do hide the x-axis serifs in chart.js 2?

Tags: chart.js2

How do I hide the x-axis serifs in chart.js 2 ?
And remove all paddings around of chart?

[image]

```js
var barChartEl = document.getElementById("barChart");
    var barChart = new Chart(barChartEl, {
        type: 'bar',
        data: {
            labels: ["2012 г.", "2013 г.", "2014 г.", "2015 г."],
            datasets: [{
                data: [542, 34127, 39797, 51450]
            }]
        },
        options: {
            scales: {
                yAxes: [{
                    ticks: {
                        display: false
                    }
                }]
            }
        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.5.0/Chart.bundle.js"></script>
<canvas id="barChart" width="400" height="200"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

resolve:

```
scales: {
    xAxes: [{
        gridLines: {
         tickMarkLength: 0
                    }
                }]
            }
```